# How to Get sharepoint Application Sign In Page URL Programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint Application When Claims Based Authentication types are enabled, a URL for redirecting the user to the Sign In page is required.

I want to get that Which Login Page is set Either default or Custom and if it is custom i want to get the 'Custom Sign in Page' URL programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, explains how it works: 
        "http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2012/06/11/custom-sign-in-and-sign-out-page/"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to provide a URL if using Windows Authentication in claims mode.  The default login page is _login/default.aspx  If a custom login page is used, it will be listed in central admin.

A URL for redirecting the user to the Sign In page is required only when using a trusted identity provider.  In that case you can get the login page by setting the identity provider to a variable ex. $TIP = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "YourTrustedIdentityProviderName" then running $TIP.ProviderUri

That will show the host that is being redirected to for login.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time this post was answered but I was looking up how to get the custom sign in page Url programatically. This is not very documented so here's what I've found:

- Get a SPWebApplication object (in my case I used an SPSite.WebApplication property.)
- Find the WebApplication IisSetting that has FormsClaimsAuthentication
- Get the Claims Authentication Login Redirection Url

Here:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysiteurl")
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<SPUrlZone, SPIisSettings> zone in site.WebApplication.IisSettings)
    {
        if(zone.Value.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider != null)
        {
            string customSignInPageUrl = zone.Value.ClaimsAuthenticationRedirectionUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

This gave my the relative path to the custom Sign In page I've set in my central admin.

In my case I was coding my own FBA management solution and I wanted the admin to be able to go see the login page even when already logged in.